# Not able to use the extensions on visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10, visual-studio-code

I want to use `Visual Studio Code` in Windows 10.
As a user of `vim editor`, I have been used to coding in way of `vim`.

So i want to install the `amVim` extension on Visual Studio Code.

**Issue 1 :**

```
it keep saying "installing" after i clicked "install".
```

**Issue 2 :**

Then i went to the github page of `amVim` and download the file and put it into `.vscode/extensions/`. However, when i started to use it to code, it showed many warning:

when i try to delete something:

```
command 'amVim.backspace' not found
```

when i try to escape the insert mode:

```
command 'amVim.escape' not found
```

it didn't work at all!

then i change to ubuntu and download the version for linux. it works well. i can download the extension.

how can i fix this problem with Windows ?

Comment: Failure to install an extension can happen if you are behind a proxy.  See [this link](http://blog.majcica.com/2016/04/07/visual-studio-code-behind-a-proxy/)

Answer (score 1):

I have also been trying to use vscode but really like to input and edit using vim commands. I have tried at least three different vim emulators on vscode and have encountered the problem you describe as well as some more serious freezing problems. If I install either amVim or vimStyle, my entire system will block if it ever enters the suspend state. I did some anecdotal experimentation and if I disabled the the plugins my system would no longer freeze. I have been using the Vim plugin by vscodevim and so far things are stable. I did encounter the same error messages about backspace and other commands but only when I was on Ubuntu. It would seem to be early times for associating vscode with vim style input.

Comment: I reached the same problem under Manjaro/Arch linux. Noone vim extension for keyboard does work.

Comment: I ran into this issue when one of my VSCode extensions was crashing the extension manager. Disabling the extension in question (for me it was Live SASS Compiler) fixed the issue.